# How to use Aurelia third party plugin with without typescript definition file?

Tags: plugins, typescript, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia and Typescript. I am trying to use a the aurelia-dialog plugin inside of my project. I have follow all the necessary steps and am getting an error "cannot find module "aurelia-dialog". The offending line is

```
import {DialogService, DialogController} from "aurelia-dialog";
```

I am pretty sure all of the config is set up correctly because this is my only error. I have

```
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .developmentLogging()
  .plugin('aurelia-dialog');
```

Do I need to create a typescript definition file for this to work, if so how? Or am I missing something and this should work as-is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the aurelia-dialog build hasn't been configured to produce TypeScript definition files yet. This will probably be added soon.  In the meantime you could add an `aurelia-dialog.d.ts` file to your project with the following:

```typescript
declare module 'aurelia-dialog' {
  export class DialogService {
    open(settings: any): Promise;
  }
  export class DialogController {
    constructor(renderer, settings, resolve, reject);
    ok(result: any): Promise<DialogResult>;
    cancel(result: any): Promise<DialogResult>;
    error(message): Promise<DialogResult>;
    close(ok: boolean, result: any): Promise<DialogResult>;
    settings: {lock: boolean, centerHorizontalOnly: boolean };
  }

  export class DialogResult {
    wasCancelled: boolean;
    output: any;
    constructor(cancelled: boolean, result: any);
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is 2.5 years old but I'm still coming to the question because I'm having the same issue. Is this still the best answer? Aurelia hasn't gotten this fixed?