# Cannot find module aurelia-dialog

Tags: aurelia

I have installed in my project directory via

```
jspm install aurelia-dialog
```

successfully.

I have modified main.ts to the following:

```
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .developmentLogging()
  .plugin('aurelia-dialog');

aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
```

I am attempting to import w/

```
import {DialogService} from 'aurelia-dialog';
import {DialogController} from 'aurelia-dialog';
```

and it results in "Cannot find module aurelia-dialog"

Note, it is showing in my dependencies.json and being pulled down to jspm_packages/npm/....

Comment: is the error a typescript error or a console error from runtime (in devtools, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Aurelia third party plugin with without typescript definition file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046339/how-to-use-aurelia-third-party-plugin-with-without-typescript-definition-file)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this thread: [How to use Aurelia third party plugin with without typescript definition file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046339/how-to-use-aurelia-third-party-plugin-with-without-typescript-definition-file)

This package doesn't come with typescript definition files....thus, if you are using typescript, you will have to create them yourself.